# システム紹介ではなく、いい質問をするためのツアーがあったほうがいいのでは？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, ツアー

質問の投稿者にツアーを読むよう促そうと思ったのですが、ツアーの中心に`どういうシステムなのか`があり、重要なアクションにおいて、メタ議論を理解しているユーザーと、ツアーのみを読んだユーザーとの間に認識のギャップがあると感じました。また、ブランクがあるユーザーがすぐに馴染める情報が必要です。

ツアーを共通認識を形成する場として役立てる必要性を感じます。

Comment: ツアーにもう少し[質問にあたって](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)が書かれている方が実用的かと思うのですが

Comment: ちなみに、メタに「[FAQ記事の一覧](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1484/8000)」という投稿があるのはご存知でしょうか。日本語版ではまだ少ないですが、[英語版SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/2818869)や[メタSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/286934)には結構な量の情報があります。

Comment: @unarist  申し訳ないが、全く知りませんでした。

Comment: ですが２０００点以上の人にその重要な運用ポリシーFAQは正しく認知されていると思いますか、特に３００点過ぎたあたりのユーザーはキューにアクセスできるようになりサイトの使い方を教え出す信用度です。
そのFAQの問題点は、英語版では国籍問わず英語が使える人が対象１７．５億人ですが、日本では１.３億人という規模の違いで１００以上のの更新され続けるFAQを管理することは難しいと思います。なぜなら、日本語と英語を話せる人の人口はもっと少なくその人たちの大きな負担になってしまいます。できることなら日本語と英語を話せる人々にはMetaではなく積極的に難しい問題への回答を翻訳してもらったほうが利用者に利益があると思います。英語からの方針の輸入としても翻訳しやすくローカライズされたものだけでも十分だと思います。

Comment: いいえ、そもそも知らないという人が大半ではないでしょうか（私の想像ですが）。あなたがご自身で投稿された回答を見て、そういえばこんなものがあったな、という感じで参考資料として挙げましたが、私もFAQよりチュートリアルが必要なのかなと思います。それが「ツアー」ページである必要はありませんが、「まずここを見てください」と言えるようなものがあるといいのかなと。

Comment: システム面のFAQは私はよく参照しますが、まずユーザーから求められるのはむしろこのサイトでの過ごし方、マナー、考え方等々でしょう。これらは英語版と異なる点も多いですし、日本語版での議論を元に形成されるべきものですから、そのまま輸入する必要はありません。あなたが挙げたような質問にFAQタグを付けようかと考えるぐらいです（が、議論がそのままFAQとして読みやすいわけではないので、改めてまとめたほうがいいだろうなと・・・）。

Answer (score 9):

個人的には，この目的であまり詳細なツアー/チュートリアルを用意することには慎重であるべきだと思います(FAQのまとめ，くらいなら丁度いいと思いますが)．理由は大まかにいえば，i) そういうのを読まないタイプの初心者には効果がないし，ii)そういうのを読むタイプの初心者には余分な負担を強いることになるからです．まず初心者に読ませる文章としては，現状の[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)で十分だと思います．

僕はこういったサイトに参加するときにはとりあえずマニュアルを読むタイプの初心者でした． 今でも覚えていますが，stackoverflow を初めて利用した時に感銘を受けたのは，[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)の簡潔さでした:

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

びくびくしている初心者に優しい文体で，これをチェックすれば，とりあえず怒られることはなさそうというつよい安心感を与えてくれるものです．続いて[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)，[What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)，などを読み， *practical, answerable* のような表現に込められた意味を理解し(ようとし)，自分でそれらの項目で挙げられているチェックポイントを確認して，どうやら大丈夫そうであると判断した後，震える指で（もちろん誇張！）質問を投稿しました．幸い僕の最初の質問は +5 を頂け，問題ないという僕の判断は間違っていなかったようです．

ここで僕がある程度の自信をもって投稿できたのは，初心者が読むべきと思われる多くない数のガイドライン/ヘルプの中で，極小数の，簡潔ながらはっきりしたチェックすべき項目が挙げられていたからです．ここにもし追加で「質問の際のベストプラクティス」などといって長々と色々なことが書き連ねられていたら，僕はそれらを全部読もうとし，消耗してその晩はブラウザを閉じ，面倒になって一旦今抱えている問題を忘れようとし，なかなか投稿にはたどり着かなかったでしょう．

初心者がまず気にするべきことは，そして我々が彼らに気をつけてもらうべきことは，ひどい質問をしないことです． ja.stackoverflow を眺めていてたくさんの downvote を受けているような初心者による投稿は（本家 stackoverflow でも大体そうですが），殆ど，乱暴にいえば次のような反問ではじけるようなもののように思うのです．

- 結局何が訊きたいの / どうなってるの / なにをどうしたいの?
- もしあなたがその分野に詳しかったとして，たったそれだけの情報で答えられると本気で思う?
- 検索すればすぐわかるけど，一瞬でも自分で調べようとした？若しくはそれ以上の情報が欲しいのですか？　（これには若干議論があるようですが，典型的な「質が低く，回答者を一方的に消耗させる質問」のひとつの類型がこうなっているのは確かだと思います）．
- <del>あんた馬鹿ぁ?</del>

（最後のは冗談です）．

新規の質問者がこうした質問をするのを防ぐのに，現状以上のチュートリアルが必要でしょうか．[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)とそこからリンクされている文章を普通に読めば，それで十分「ふつうによい質問」はできるのではないかと思います．

---

ここは随想：スタックオーバーフローには「ここはこういうサイトです」というのがあって，それに資するような質問と回答が良い投稿，それを助けるためのシステムがある，という流れで，そこから境界上の案件について「こういうときってどうすればいいんだろう」というのをメタで意見交換するという形だと勝手に思っているので，そもそもメタの議論からFAQの集まり以上の縛りが発生するのには若干違和感を持ったりします…がこの意見はごく個人的なものです．

Answer (score 1):

Yosh　さんへ

> 初心者が読むべきと思われる多くない数のガイドライン/ヘルプの中で，極小数の，簡潔ながらはっきりしたチェックすべき項目が挙げられていたからです．

確かに、具体的なチェック項目がありますが、バッジやタグ、権限などのように詳細へ入っていけるリンクがないです。そこに、情報アクセシビリティの問題を感じます。

---

[質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1979/%E8%A8%8E%E8%AD%B0%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81) は、投票結果をの原因を調べたり、方針の変化を確認したり質問前に重複を防ぐために確認できるようにしたものです。

> 縛りが発生するのには若干違和感を持ったりします

まとめの時に注意した点があります。
回答が多くなっているものはまとめないようにしました。回答への反論や質問への反論で多くなっていると考えたためです。統一性のない意見をまとめてしまい方針とすることは利用するユーザーにとって良くないと考えたからです。

Comment: >前半: 質問文の「質問の投稿者に」というのに引っ張られ，つい初心者への質問のためのチュートリアルに絞った文章を書いていました．バッジやタグ，権限についてはそれらのヘルプを見ればよく，僕としてはやはり現状以上の"チュートリアルは"不要と思います（上で十分強調しませんでしたが，過去の議論のまとめに価値があるとは思っています）．> 後半: ある程度共有された見解に絞っておられるとのこと，丁寧なお仕事に脱帽です．