# 質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方, 回答の仕方, 投票の仕方, よくある質問の案

> [Stack Overflowの管理はコミュニティが行うため、このコミュニティがルールを決めるべきです。](/a/311/10972)

メタが課題としているのはルールの制定、コミュニティの強化、利用者の増加、もちろん質問と回答の管理もあります。

コミュニティのわかりやすさを向上させるために、メタ内に散在している討議をまとめる必要性がありました。

そこで、質問、回答、投票、コメント等の一般的な活動についての討議をまとめ、一定の水準・品質・基準を確保することを目的とします。

- [使い方全般](/a/1982)
- [質問の仕方](/a/1980)
- [質問者にしてほしいこと](/a/1981)
- [回答の仕方](/a/1983)
- [コメント/投票/その他](/a/1984)
- [編集履歴](/a/1985)

[←質問にあたって](/help/asking)

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

ここへのリンク`[質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ](/q/1979)`
回答はいつでも誰でも変更可能になっています。

Comment: まとめてくれて、ありがとうございます！英語版では[meta-tag:faq]のまとめがあります：http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites　日本語でもこのようにしたらどうですかね？一つの投稿にまとめるより、インデックスを作って、内容を説明したら探しやすくなると思います。

Comment: コミュニティwikiを編集するには信用度が100位上ないと行けません。とりあえず、回答として追加したら？

Comment: faqタグ追加不可とのことです。

Comment: @user10972 FAQ案のタグをつけてみました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**使い方全般**

---

- [モデレーションでコメントの削除をする際は技術的な内容を残してほしい](/q/1938)
- [知らない間にコメントが削除されている](/q/1971)

投票は個人の判断に委ねられます。気分を害す表現での、揉め事・喧嘩・紛争・炎上のおそれのある場合、速やかに通報してください。予告なしに該当の質問、回答またはコメントが編集、削除、クローズ、ロックされ、ペナルティーが科せられます。投票、通報及びモデレーターの判断は常に適切なものとして保護され、その責任を誰も負うことはありません。また、それらの匿名性は常に優先的に確保されます。
アイコン画像が理由で通報される場合もあるかもしれません。暴力的、グロテスクなもの、卑猥な物、は使用しないでください。

---

- [ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](/q/1649)
- [句読点として「，．」を使うのは推奨されないか？](/q/1464)
- [回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](/q/1558)
- [投稿者と他のユーザーの間で編集合戦になるのを防ぐために](/q/1857)
- [回答の中に質問者から回答者への返信を書くのはわかりにくい](/q/330)
- [どの程度コメントに丁寧な言葉遣いを求めますか](/q/1900)

すべての投稿で標準語と丁寧語を推奨しています。

編集について、質問投稿者による大幅な質問文の削除、書き換えを禁止しています。'その[理由](/q/1558)は一貫性が確保できないためです。'質問者は質問文に、回答者は回答文に追記編集をしてください。
もし、前提条件や解決したいこと自体が変化した場合、新しい質問として投稿してください。

投稿者以外の編集はタイトル、タグ、コードで囲むなど機能を有効に活用する編集にしてください。'その理由は、[編集合戦](/q/1857)、[過剰編集](/q/1633/#comment662_1643)を防ぐためです。'また、本文中の表現を変更することも投稿者以外控えてください。[理由](/q/1649)

ただし、Wikiでは積極的な編集が望まれます。

---

- [未投稿ですが、この質問・回答は可能ですか](/q/1566)
- [「Unity初心者がとりくむべきチュートリアル」はタグWikiに入れた方がよい？](/q/1384)
- [質問の基準の参考に-qa-is-hard-let-s-go-shopping-を翻訳してみました](/q/1432)

リストやロードマップを作ってもらう質問は投稿可能です。その場合は、質問者自身でWiki回答を投稿してください。初回の回答の品質としては７項目以上を示してリンクやタイトルだけでなく、説明を１〜２行程度示してください。また、絶版のものや入手困難などの理由で平等性が欠落している場合は明記してください。
クローズ・マイナスの基準として、回答が半永久的ではなく負担となる(年に数回の刷新)場合、リストが非常に多くなる数ページ及ぶもの場合、既にリストが他のウェブページに存在している場合などがあります。

基準を厳しくしている理由は過去の討議と質の高い質問、主観的な質問と言った基準のためです。細かい討議を避けるため回答とセットで質が高くできるリスト質問については回答の品質基準を設定しました。

---

- [分析: 「いいライブラリ / ツールはありませんか」系のQ&Aでもっと欲張るには](/q/1512)
- [javascriptのフレームワークの選定について-を改善するには](/q/1519)
- [参考ブログ記事-いい-主観的-よくない-主観的](/q/1485)

ライブラリやソフトウェア、ツールを探す質問も可能です。求める条件を詳細に示してください。回答者はコメントで回答範囲を絞る条件を示してください。また、それがほかと比べ優れている理由を統計情報や実測データ等を示し数年間にわたって有効な回答をしてください。
それでも、あまりに回答が多い場合、炎上した場合は質問がクローズまたは、ロックされます。

理由：その都度、主観的な質問として討議の必要の無いように前提のある質問と根拠のある回答を心がけてもらいたいと基準を設けました。

---

- [英語の質問は英語版の方へ移行できますか？](/q/1933/)
- [日本語のソフトウェアに関する質問が英語で寄せられた場合](/q/1815)
- [日本人じゃないですけど、回答することができると思います。いいですか？](/q/1959)

質問と回答が日本語であれば、国籍及び人種は問われません。
注意事項：英語で質問しないでください（[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)に移行されます。）。母国語が英語である場合には、日本語に翻訳してください。同時に、あなたの母国語が英語であることをお伝え下さい。

If questions and answers are both in Japanese, race and nationality do not matter.
Note: Please do not ask questions in English. If you do, they will be migrated to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). When your native language is English, please translate into Japanese. Please also state that your native language is English.

英語が禁止と思われる文面の理由：編集の方針[過剰編集](/a/1984)と矛盾する可能性があるため。

---

- [同一人物が内容が重複する質問を投稿していることに気づいたときに採るべき対応は](/q/1950)

トップページに反映されるまでに最低でも５分ほどかかります。その間にわかりやすいかコードが抜けていないかを一度見直すことをおすすめします。
もし、ユーザーが悪意を持って投稿していると判断できる場合、マイナス票を投じ速やかにスパムとして通報してください。マイナス票の多いユーザーの質問は制限されます。
同じ質問であっても投稿して良いものとしては十分に古くまだ回答がない質問があります。これは、質問者が変わり情報共有がスムースになることが想定されるためです。

---

- [英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?](/q/292)
- [英語が残っている箇所-プライベートベータでの質問方法-ページの-関連サイト](/q/292)

すべての英語版のトピックスを翻訳することは不可能で、決まっているルールをただ単に翻訳するのではなくなぜルールになったのか知る必要があります。より多くの利点を取り入れることができる最低限のルールをメタで討議する必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

### コメント/投票/その他

---

- [建設的なコメントとはどういうものですか？](/q/1992)
- [解法を促す書き込みはコメント欄ではなく回答欄に書いてほしい](/q/1938)
- [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](/q/1812)

確認したい設定、バージョン、外部環境などや、回答にあたって規模や範囲を絞るの情報を確認す‌​るために利用してください。 
ちょっとしたアドバイスで解決することもあります。アドバイスは回答として投稿してください。
コメント欄ではリンクのみを示すことが可能ですが、回答がリンクのみですと、リンク切れとなった場合、不適切なものになります。リンク切れとなった場合は通報してください。（リンクが複数の場合、編集、一つの場合、削除になると思います。）

---

- [質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？](/q/1876)
- [質問の投票ボタン：努力した跡がみられる、実用的で分かりやすく書かれている](/q/1896)
- [そうだ-投票しよう](/q/1528)

反対票、通報の基準として

- 回答
  -間違っているなどの不正確な回答
  -リンクのみの不安定な回答
  -ウイルスのような危険な回答
  -質問への回答ではないコメント
  -質問への回答ではない質問
- コメント
  -口喧嘩をしている
  -リンク切れ
- 質問
  -支離滅裂な質問
  -重複した質問
  -コードのみの質問
  -その他クローズ

---

- [クローズ理由のまとめ](/q/1729)

  1. 質問内容目的がはっきりしない
     -質問者が情報を共有していない
     ex.動作の説明がない。必要なコードがない。コードのみ。暗黙の仕様。
  2. 質問の範囲が広すぎる
     ?
  3. 主観的な答えしか集まらない
     おすすめを聞く質問
     *確かな情報ソースや専門知識と経験、事実に基づいた回答ができるような質問にしてください*
     おすすめを聞くのはNGだが、利用者が多いソフトを聞くことはOK
  4. リスト系質問
     -回答と一緒に投稿されていない。
     -更新頻度が高く負担となる。
     -リストが非常に多い。
     -既にリストが他のウェブページに存在している。

---

- [編集の頻度の指針はありますか？](/q/1988)

システムによって、高頻度で編集はできません。
確定後5分間の編集は一度の編集として扱われ、「本日すでに自分の投稿のうち 5 件を編集しています (最も最近の投稿を除く)。次に編集できるのは明日です。」というエラーが存在し、自分の質問を目立たせる目的では利用できません。

---

- [新しいタグの許可の要望: playframework](/q/1425)
- [新しいタグの許可の要望: google-app-engine](/q/365)
- [actionscriptタグの追加を提案します](/q/1681)

利用したいタグがなく信用度が不足している場合、新しいタグの要望をしてください。

Answer (score 1):

### 質問の仕方

---

- [適切な質問かの討議-面白イースターエッグ](/q/1417)
- [オフトピックかの判断: プログラマに関する英語の質問について](/q/1500)

実用性のない大喜利のような質問は控えてください。
文化までを含めた翻訳が必要な場合も控えてください。

---

- [質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？](/q/1678)

このサイトでは、メンバやプロパティ、関数、メソッドなどを聞くことができますが、日本語リファレンスがあるものは質問として評判がよくありません。

---

- [適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問](/q/1489)

このサイトでは、クイズ形式であっても質問は可能です。ただし、質問と回答を同時に投稿したくない場合そのことを本文に書きましょう。投票はそのコンテンツのユニークさや情報エントロピーに基づいて回答と質問に投票されます。

---

- [ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問をどう考えるか](/q/1541)

個別解釈の問題でなければ可能ですが、裁判になった場合、サイト及び回答者は責任を負いません。

---

- [「コードが思い浮かびません」という質問はどう聞けばよいですか？](/q/1688)

実現したいことを書いてください。極力丁寧語を利用し、どこまで出来ているかも示してもらったほうが角が立たずにスムーズに回答が得られます。

---

- [質問は細かく細分化するべき？それとも、得た回答から話を飛躍させても良い？](/q/1663)

質問の軸が異なる場合、または、既にある回答で解決できなかった場合、新しい質問として投稿してください。

---

- [デバッグ方法を勉強すべき質問について](/q/1813)
- [該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](/q/1595)

このサイトでは、プログラミングの基礎の質問であってもすることができます。
回答者は[簡単に見える質問を見つけた場合、非常にいい回答をしてください](/a/1603)

---

- [iosの基本的な使い方についての質問はここでしても問題ない](/q/367)
- [プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？](/q/1546)

サーバー・デスクトップ・ラップトップ・タブレット問わず、パーティションもOSも基本的な使い方も質問ができます。環境を新調した場合のコードなどの移行が必要な場合についても質問ができます。しかし、検索で即座に解決できるものについての投票はシビアです。

---

- [学校の宿題は回答するべきでしょうか](/q/1805)

このサイトでは、現在、学校の宿題をそのまま投稿投稿することは可能です。しかし、提出期限について保証は一切致しません。また、コードのレベルが授業範囲内で収まることも保証しません。

---

- [質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？](/q/1678)

このサイトでは、メンバやプロパティ、関数、メソッドなどを聞くことができますが、日本語リファレンスがあるものは質問として評判がよくありません。

Answer (score 1):

### 質問者にしてほしいこと

---

- [回答にいくつか付け加えて解決した場合、回答を編集してもよい？](/q/1794)
- [勝手に質問を編集されるのを禁止するオプションが欲しい](/q/1630)

質問と回答の整合性が良くなる場合は編集をしてください。半分以上編集が必要な場合は新しく回答を投稿し、過剰な編集をしないよう心がけてください。

---

- [質問が自己解決できた場合](/q/1747)
- [タイトルに "クローズ" と含まれた質問の対処](/q/1676)

質問が自己解決した場合、回答を投稿し回答を承認することを推奨しております。どうしても削除する場合は、ユーザー登録が終了しており回答がついていない質問については削除可能です。

---

- [クローズされた質問でも「自己解決した場合は自分で回答」してもらうべき？](/q/1775)

サイトによってクローズされた場合、回答の必要はありません。それでも、質問と回答として残したい場合は、編集を頑張ってください。

---

- [よりよい回答を求めて回答の承認を保留にしてもいいのでしょうか](/q/1906)
- [回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](/q/1784)

回答を承認するタイミングはいつでも自由ですが、納得できないのであればその回答にコメントを残すほうがよりよい回答を得ることができます。

---

- [ありがとう-というコメントは禁止？](/q/1693)

回答者全員にコメントでお礼をすると、後から見る人がどれが役に立ったのかわからない場合があります。
投票・承認機能を活用してください。

Answer (score 1):

**回答の仕方**

---

- [どのような場合にwikiは有効ですか](/q/1583)

基本的にリスト質問のように多くの人が参加的に編集する回答です。
過去には、コメントで解決した質問の回答としてそのコメントをWiki回答としています。しかし、サイトの負担が多くなりがちです。

---

- [初歩的な質問への回答に-コピペできるようなコードを含めるのはよいことか](/q/1515)

コード、コマンド、原因の指摘だけでも十分に回答として有効ですが、解説やノウハウとセットの回答が最も良い回答と言えます。見つけたら積極的に投票しましょう。

---

- [質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー](/q/257)

引用する場合は、最低限URLを示してください。回答として自身の表現が含まれない場合は、コメントへURLを投稿する程度にとどめてください。

---

- [他のサイトでの回答をスタックオーバーフローにコピーすることは推奨されますか](/q/1955)

コメントのリンクで解決した場合、読んだところを最小限の引用を回答としてください。また、ちょっとしたアドバイスで解決することもあります。アドバイスは解答欄に記載し、コメント欄では回答が２つあるけどどちらにしようかと言った回答を絞るために必要な情報を聞き出すために使ってください。

---

- [ソフトウェアに意図しない挙動を行わせる質問は許容されるのか？](/q/1633)
- [脆弱性のあるコードが回答されていたら、どう対応するべき？](/q/1800)

このサイトでは、あなたの投稿するコードはあなたの責任で公開されるものとします。コードの利用者も利用者自身の責任で利用するものとします。
バグや脆弱性がある場合については危険性を示すコメントを残し、回答ができる場合は回答をしてください。学習以外の目的と思われる質問では投票者は優先的にバグや脆弱性の少ないものへ投票してください。
実行した人に危害を加えると判断できる場合、速やかに通報してください。

Answer (score 0):

### 編集履歴

---

- 意図的にまとめていない

  - 議論中
  - まとめにくい
  - それらの派生
  - 一時的に

[どこまで質問に完璧さを求めるか](/q/1737)
[このサイトは質問者に対して厳しすぎではないでしょうか](/q/1878)
[「探索アルゴリズムの比較」という質問は「質問の範囲が広すぎる」か？](/q/1716)
[クローズ理由のまとめ](/q/1729)
[英語で回答しても構いませんか？](/q/1990/)
[タグを作成する基準はありますか (eg. N 個以上でタグを作る)](/q/2007/)

---

まとめたもの：質問の数
[質問の仕方](/questions/tagged/%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%95%e6%96%b9)：16
[質問のクローズ](/questions/tagged/%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ba)：２
[クローズ理由](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ba%e7%90%86%e7%94%b1)：３
[回答の仕方](/questions/tagged/%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%95%e6%96%b9)：5
[投票の仕方](/questions/tagged/%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%95%e6%96%b9)：5
[サポート](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88)：４8
[討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)：１34
[コメント](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88)：6
[リスト質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)：3
[編集](/questions/tagged/%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86)：6

適切にタグ付けをしましょう。

---

`2015/9/13 10:00`現在、上記のリンク以外で質問、回答、コメント、編集に関わるものでまとめていないものは：[ありません](/questions/tagged/%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)

Comment: できればメタ情報最も最後に表示させたい