# StackOverflow How To: 質問のしかた

Tags: 討議, サポート, 質問の仕方, よくある質問の案

## 0. 目的

スタックオーバーフローで、新規ユーザーが質問を行いたくなったときに、知っておいた方がよいことを整理する。

## 1. 質問するにあたって

#### 1.1 すでに同じ質問がなされていないか調べてみましょう。

サイトの上の「検索...」の欄から、今おこなおうとしている質問がすでに行われていないかどうか、確認してみましょう。特に、

- スペースで区切ると、それらは and 条件として検索されます。
- [タグ名] で検索すると、タグ名のタグに絞って投稿を検索できます。

検索例:

```
[git] rebase
```

#### 1.2 既存質問がなかった場合は: 今抱えている問題を整理しましょう。

本サイト(スタックオーバーフロー)に限らず、技術コミュニティにおいて質問を行う場合には、心掛けた方が良い事柄がいくつかあります。

結城浩先生の、[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html) などがよくまとまっているので、ご参考ください。

本サイトにおいて重要なポイントを、ピックアップしますと、以下になります。(メイリングリストではないので、多少記述は違うかもれしれませんが、だいたいそのまま参考にできます)

- 要件をタイトルに書く: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#subject
- 実行手順を明確にする: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#procedure
- 期待した結果を書く: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#result
- 実際の値, エラーメッセージを明記する: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#cond, http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#paste
- ソースを載せる: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#list
- 関連する投稿があれば、リンクする: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#log
- 検索エンジンで５分調べてみる: http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#search

#### 1.3 質問を行う

- タイトルは、質問を完結に要件を表す文章にしましょう。
- 本文は、マークダウンが利用可能です。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
- **タグを適切に付与しましょう。** コミュニティのユーザーによっては、タグでフォローする質問を分類している人もいます。自分の投稿が、その分野の詳しい人の目に留まるよう、適切なタグを付与しましょう。

## 2. 注意

いくつかのタイプの質問は、本サイトでは取り扱わない方針です。そのような質問は、場合によってはクローズされてしまいます。

#### 2.1 プログラミングの技術的な質問でない

本サイトは、主にプログラミングに関する技術的なトピックを扱うサイトです。トピックから外れた質問を行った場合、質問がクローズされる場合があります。

#### 2.2 回答が収束しないタイプの投稿を避ける

以下のタイプの質問は、回答が収束しない可能性が高く、質問がクローズされる場合があります。

- 主観的な質問
- 買い物型質問 (例: Android初心者が取り組むべきチュートリアルを教えてください)
- 回答に求められる情報が多い (まじめな回答に、本１冊必要な質問、など)

## 3. Be Nice

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: 失礼しました。先ほどの重複は質問ではなく回答でしたね。タイトルがタグみたいなので`howto`タグに出来ないですかね？

Comment: 参考: [質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1979/19110)